# Constant $c$ in Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, speed-of-light, units, unit-conversion

I met some of examples of force in studying classical dynamics, and Lorentz force was represented as 
$$ \mathbf{F}=\frac{q}{c} \mathbf{\dot{r}} \times \mathbf{B}  $$
I've searched for meaning of $c$, but I have no idea. Could anyone please explain it for me?

Comment: The form of the equation you've seen is using cgs-Gaussian units. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Equation_.28cgs_units.29) for more.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks a lot. I should've checked more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Lorentz force in Gaussian Units. The constant $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum.